# manually submitting symfony form results in CSRF error

Tags: forms, symfony

I would like to be able to manually submit a symfony form with data I create but it seems I am missing the CSRF token in the submitted data and so the validation fails.

The form is simple - just one field (let's say 'name' for argument) as a text field with no constraints.

```
$data = [];
if ($someCondition) {
    $data['name'] = 'steve';
}
$form = $this->createForm('FooType', $data);
if (!empty($data)) {
    $form->submit($data);
} else {
    $form->handleRequest($request);
}
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // do something
}
```

if I set `$data['name']`  the form submits but I get `The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.`

so obviously, I am missing the token. I know I can disable the CSRF protection, but I don't want to do this as there is also an option to 'normally' interact with the form.

How to I submit a proper token or override this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you tagged this as `symfony2` question. With that in mind, you can supply a valid CSRF token by injecting it into your data, thought, solution differ in `<2.6` and `>=2.6` version, as far as I'm aware.

### **Pre `2.6`** version:

```
$provider = $this->get('form.csrf_provider');
$token = $provider->generateCsrfToken(''); // INTENTION = empty_string, by default
$data['<<YOUR_FORM_NAME']['_token'] = $token; // be sure to change the form name
```

### Versions `2.6`+

The thing is a bit different as forms now use `TokenManagerInterface` provided by `Security` component:

```
$tokenId = ....;
$token= (string) $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken($tokenId);
$tokenValue = $token->getValue();
```

Now, the `$tokenId` can be many things, as described in a Form's public test:

```
$tokenId = $options['csrf_token_id'] ?: 
                ($form->getName() ?: 
                    get_class($form->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType()));
```

But if you look into this, the default will be `$form->getName()`, up until `2.8`. I think that `2.8` removed abstraction from the `getName()` method, thus, the `2.8` and later will user the clunky value:

```
get_class($form->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType())
```

This all holds true, unless you injection `csrf_token_id` option in your form type.

### **UPDATE:**

Ok, so it seems my bad presumption was about the token key. While you did get the valid token, that one was not used. In my example, I had separate FormType namespaced `AppBundle\Form\SomeFooType` and the actual token id that was used was `some_foo`.

I have made a pastebin of the working example (version `2.8.8`, same worked in `3.1.2` as expected): http://pastebin.com/ks2jSeh7

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: hello and thank you for your response. I *am* using Symfony 2.8 (and will eventually upgrade to 3.x), so I used the following: `$data['_token'] = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken(get_class($form->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType()))->getValue();` and it produces a token string as expected, but I still get the same error, `The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.` if I set the array like `$data[$form->getName()]['_token']` then I get the same error (as above) but ALSO get another error, `This form should not contain extra fields.` Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, let me roll out some quick foobar project (I have written the above without actually trying) and we should be able to come up with a workaround...

Comment: I figured out a way to disable the CSRF protection based on the conditions (e.g. `if ($someCondition)` above). I guess this solution works as well.

Comment: Yes, that also could be used, but see if updated answer can fit you better :)

Comment: yes your updated answer works for me. marked as correct. thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: by the way - I did `$data['_token'] = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken($form->getName())->getValue();`